# getting error when trying to insert new row in dataset table

Tags: c#, datarow

I am getting error at where datarow object is created.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AMIT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Amit;Integrated Security=true");
        con2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from  hotel.country", con2);

        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        SqlCommandBuilder sb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da2);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        da2.Fill(ds2);
       /* GridView2.DataSource = ds2;
        GridView2.DataBind();*/

        DataRow dr = ds2.Tables["hotel.country"].NewRow();
        dr[ds2.Tables[TextBox1.Text].Columns[0].ColumnName] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr[ds2.Tables[TextBox1.Text].Columns[1].ColumnName] = TextBox3.Text;
        da2.Update(ds2);
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: i don't know why the guy who just commented deleted his post because it solved my problem...that is i cannot use table name in ds2.Tables[""] instead i should use number.

Comment: Removed it because I there was some information about Stored Procedures in it, and you are using a select command. I changed my answer now.

Comment: And If You will have more than 5 tables, will you remember all the numbers? Try `DataRow dr = ds2.Tables["country"].NewRow()`
Also it would be much easier if You created Your own Dataset like DsHotel with table Country and so on. Then it would be
`DsHotel.CountryRow dr = DsHotel.Country.NewRow();
dr.YourColumnName = ....`

Comment: i tried with adding name of table but that was causing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mapping like:

```
da2.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Hotel.Country");
```

Or access it by:

```
ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();
```

**EDIT:**

This might even be easier if you want to use a table name.

```
da2.Fill(ds2, "Hotel.Country");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
    DataRow dr = ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();
    dr[ds2.Tables[TextBox1.Text].Columns[0].ColumnName] = TextBox2.Text;
    dr[ds2.Tables[TextBox1.Text].Columns[1].ColumnName] = TextBox3.Text;
    da2.Update(ds2);
```

May be this can help you....